# Toggle between 2 different menus (Reactjs + Material UI)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've created a mega menu, and I've added Switcher, the idea is simple, if switch is off, show 1st menu, if the switch is on show the second menu.

Currently, when switched to on, it shows the second menu, but when it's off it shows nothing, only background, could someone help me with this, probably someone already faced with issue.

Comment: This is just a matter of of dynamic rendering based on conditions. Store some boolean as state which is true if switch is on and false if off, then render the correct menu based on that boolean state. If you want a more detailed answer you should post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a conditional

Example:

```
export default function ComponentWithBackgroud(){
 const [toggleOn, setToggleOn] = useState(false);

 return <section class="menuContainer">
    <input type="checkbox" onChange={()=>setToggleOn(!toggleOn)}>
    {toggleOn ? <Firstmenu /> : <SecondMenu />}
</section>
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so much for your help